# Oracle DB trigger fails, then succeeds with same input

Tags: oracle11g, database-trigger

In my project, there is a DB trigger that gets input from an application. The application populates a table, the trigger takes the table rows as inputs, and populates a different table as output. The trigger has been performing fine for years.

A few months ago, the trigger started failing for a huge number of inputs, giving a general exception. When manually trying to reprocess the errored out inputs, they get processed correctly. So now I have written a second trigger, that searches for errored out entries, and updates their status as "not processed", and the original trigger processes them correctly.

While it took care of the problem, I still cannot figure out why the first errors happen in the first place. If it were a trigger problem, the issue could be reproduced with the same input, but it can't. Any errored out input, when processed again, passes with flying colours.

What could be the problem here? When does an Oracle DB trigger throw general exception with an input, but never a second time with the same input?

Comment: What is a "general exception"?

Comment: Exceptions from lack of data is handled properly, so anything other than that would be a general exception in this case. There is a column named "STATUS" that can have values "PASS", "IGNORED", "E-NO DATA" and "E", which indicate "successful execution", "invalid requests", "exception due to lack of data" and "general exception" respectively. In this case, the errored out entried always get the status "E". Unprocessed entried has the status null. So my workaround trigger just finds entries with status "E" and makes them null.